# I can't call setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio

Hollo,
when I try to use setOnClickListener on button it did not appear at all.

[image: this image display the problem.]

I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1

Comment: please provide the code in your question instead of having an image of it.

Comment: You're using it outside your onCreate method. You must put it inside it.

Comment: do it like this...
`@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
                Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     ....
                    }
                });
}`

Comment: Thanks you. it wrorks

Answer (score 2):

Write the code inside the

> onCreate()

method. Defining listeners requires context.

Comment: Thanks you. it wrorks

Comment: @MojahedAlarour As per our SO Rules .You must accept the answer if works

Answer (score 0):

Move your code inside the `ònCreate()` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Button moveToEnglish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Englishbutton);
    moveToEnglish.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `setOnClickListener` outside of `onCreate()`.

So move your Button Declaration in its method inside onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Button moveToEnglish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Englishbutton);
    moveToEnglish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

    }
 });
}
```